# Autowired repository not connecting

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to auto wire a repository for a simple springboot application. But When I start to do java -jar for my app it says: Field bugRepository in be.tquality.demospringdb.BugController required a bean of type 'be.tquality.demospringdb.BugRepository' that could not be found.

This is the bug repository:

```
package be.tquality.demospringdb;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface BugRepository extends JpaRepository<Bug, Long> {

}
```

and my controller

```
package be.tquality.demospringdb;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class BugController {

    @Autowired
    private BugRepository bugRepository;

    @GetMapping(value = "bug/findall")
    public List<Bug> findAll(){
        return bugRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And this my actual database class

```
package be.tquality.demospringdb;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "BUG")
@Data
public class Bug implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2343243243242432341L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "TESTCASEID")
    private int testcaseid;

    @Column(name = "TESTSTEPID")
    private int teststepid;

    @Column(name = "TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private int status;

    @Column(name = "ASSIGNEE")
    private int assignee;

    @Column(name = "PROJECTID")
    private int projectid;

    @Column(name = "EXPECTEDRESULT")
    private String expectedresult;

    @Column(name = "ACTUALRESULT")
    private String actualresult;

    public Bug(){}

    public Bug(int testcaseid, int teststepid, String title, String description, int status,int assignee,int projectid,
               String expectedresult,String actualresult) {
        this.testcaseid = testcaseid;
        this.teststepid = teststepid;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.status = status;
        this.assignee = assignee;
        this.projectid = projectid;
        this.expectedresult = expectedresult;
        this.actualresult = actualresult;
    }
}
```

I really don't see what I'm doing wrong and why it cannot connect to the repository. As in my ide it can connect easily

The part that's start issues when I run java -jar is

```
2022-11-15 14:45:27.901  WARN 32225 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bugController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bugRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'be.tquality.demospringdb.BugRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2022-11-15 14:45:27.905  INFO 32225 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-11-15 14:45:28.035  INFO 32225 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-11-15 14:45:28.095 ERROR 32225 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field bugRepository in be.tquality.demospringdb.BugController required a bean of type 'be.tquality.demospringdb.BugRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'be.tquality.demospringdb.BugRepository' in your configuration.
```

My spring boot application

```
package be.tquality.demospringdb;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemospringdbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemospringdbApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the project compiled without errors? Please provide more details on which commands you are executing.

Comment: Your entity‘s @Id is of type int, but the repository uses Long.

Comment: @ChristophDahlen I changed this but stil the same issue.

Comment: @mapawa I run the command: gradle clean build jar. This has no issues and creates the jar and then I run the jar file

Comment: Remove `@Repository` apart from hurting the eyes it adds nothing. Add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated classes and your dependencies. One thing I notice is wrong they type of ID. In your entity it is an `int` in your repository it is a `Long`. Either the `int` should be `long` or the `Long` should be `Integer`.

Comment: I removed it and changed the integer and added the springbootapplicaiton code that I used @M.Deinum

Comment: Do you have a database configuration and driver? No database, no JPA no Spring Data JPA.

Comment: maybe add `@EnableJpaRepositories`